# jQuery ajax has invalid URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My ajax request looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: self.opts.url.replace('//www.', '//'),
    type: 'POST',
    ...
});
```

I put that `.replace` just to be sure. Because my URL in `opts.url` is `"http://website.com/admin/upload-image/123"`. But I can't upload an image, because I get an error in the console: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.website.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://website.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

I double-checked the URL in debug mode and it is always without a `www.`, but jQuery seems like adding it anyway. This doesn't make sense for me at all.

Also what I get from jQuery's `error` function:

```
jqXHR: Object (filled statusText with "error")
textStatus: "error"
errorThrown: ""
```

Comment: Inspect actual request in browser dev tools network. Is most likely being redirected at end point and that is not CORS enabled

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the error message, it says:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load www.website.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'www.website.com' is therefore not allowed access.

You must set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header on the www.website.com webpage. In php this is done by this:

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourwebsiteThatNeedsAccess");

Comment: there is more involved with CORS than simply one header

Comment: Yea, but why does jQuery replace URL with `www.`? It is technically incorrect URL then.